# program that senkeys a random digit

Tags: vbscript

I have to make a vbscript program that sendkey's a random 6 digit nomber, any ideas?

I tried this

```
WscriptSchell.SendKeys "randomNumber = Int( (999999 - 100000 + 1) * Rnd + 100000
```

Comment: `Wscript.Shell` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file (for example `test.vbs`) with that content and run it:

```
Randomize
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys Int((999999 - 100000 + 1) * Rnd + 100000)
```

Info:

`Randomize` must be called before `Rnd` to get random results.